# Filling DropDownList from DataTable in Mvc C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

connectionHelper.Select(query) returns datatable. I want to fill my dropdownlist in view with empList. How can I do it?

```
            var query = "SELECT ADSOYAD, EMPLOYEE_NUMBER FROM TTF_PERSONEL";
            var employeeNames = connectionHelper.Select(query);

            var empList = new List<CalisanModels>();
            var emp = new CalisanModels();

            for (int i = 0; i < employeeNames.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                var data = employeeNames.Rows[i];

                emp.EmployeeNumber = Convert.ToInt32(data["EMPLOYEE_NUMBER"]);
                emp.AdSoyad = data["ADSOYAD"].ToString();

                empList.Add(emp);
            }
```

Comment: what is the error/problem?You can always use the list of data as the `DataSource` of your dropdownlist.

Answer (score 2):

So you have got your `empList` filled now you can send it to View where it can be rendered.

Set from your Action:

```
ViewBag.EmployeeList = empList;
```

Render in your view:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Employees", new SelectList((IEnumerable<MyMvcApp.CalisanModels>)ViewBag.EmployeeList, "EMPLOYEE_NUMBER", "ADSOYAD"))
```

Similar dropdown population in action I answered before here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/yPwHDB